# Printing a sorted treemap(sorted based on values)

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, treemap

I have a sorted a TreeMap based on values, and it's printed as shown:

```
abortion-2
able-2
ab-2
aaron-2
aaa-2
aa-2
a-2
absent-1
absence-1
abraham-1
ability-1
aberdeen-1
abc-1
```

But it seems like the words with same values are being printed in the reverse sorted order:

***"abortion, able, ab, aaron, aaa, aa, a"*** instead of ***"a, aa, aaa, aaron, ab, able abortion"*** and so on.

I have even thought of adding each set of keys having same value to the TreeSet and print it out, but I couldn't iterate it based on next values.

Here is the comparator that I'm passing on to the TreeMap. Can anybody help me correcting the code to print it in the correct order?

```
 public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    Map<String, Integer> tiedMap; 

    public MyComparator(Map<String, Integer> map){
       this.tiedMap = map; 
    }        

    public int compare(String a, String b){
        if(tiedMap.get(a)>=tiedMap.get(b)){
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to print it:

```
Iterator it = tree.entrySet().iterator();
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   if(it.hasNext()){
      Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
      System.out.println(pairs.getKey()+"-"+pairs.getValue());
   }
}
```

Edit: I'm reading the input into a TreeMap, and then passing it to another TreeMap.

Edit: Code that creates TreeMaps:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();        
Words t = new Words();         
MyComparator comp = w.(new MyComparator(map));       
Map<String, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(comp); 

int size = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
   for(int i = size; i>0; i--){
       reader = buffer.readLine();
       if(map.get(reader)!=null){
          map.put(reader, map.get(reader)+1);
       }
       else
          map.put(reader, 1);                
   }
tree.putAll(map);
```

Comment: Can you include the lines of code that create both `TreeMaps` please?

Comment: A `TreeMap` cannot have duplicated "keys" (in your case a key is what the compare method returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator will return the entries sorted in reverse order based on their value alone.  Is this what you want?

Also, if you want the entries in a more predictable order you should also compare the keys:

```
public int compare(String a, String b)
{
    Integer aVal = tiedMap.get(a);
    Integer bVal = tiedMap.get(b);

    if (aVal > bVal)
    {
        return 1; // or -1 for descending order
    }
    else if (aVal < bVal)
    {
        return -1; // or 1 for descending order
    }
    else
    {
        // if values are equivalent compare on key as well
        return a.compareTo(b);
        // or for descending order:
        // return b.compareTo(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing to returning 1 helps, instead of returning 0 when they're equal.. I was returning -1 earlier.

Comment: You *really* should return 0 if they are equal (and still 1 or -1 for greater/less than).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(tiedMap.get(a)>=tiedMap.get(b)){
    return -1;
}
else
    return 1;
```

You should modify your code to return 0 when values are same. This will ensure that the relative ordering between your original keys is not changed. If that does not work you can add additional code like:

```
if (tiedMap.get(a) == tiedMap.get(b))
  return a.compareTo(b);
```

Comment: The code works when I `return 1` instead of `0`  when they are equal.

Comment: Well this might work in your current input sequence but not always. You must choose explicitly whether you want relative ordering of keys (when values are same) to be sorted or you want them to be same as input i.e leave the relative ordering of keys unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Actually by using comparator, you can sort your `HashMap, TreeMap` into ascending as well descending order.

Try out this:

```
// sort list based on comparator
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
                                   .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
        }
    });
```

This will give the output into descending order. By `interchanging the o2 and o1 only`, you will get them sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand your expectation/implementation completely but I think you need to character-to-character comparison between string a and b in compare function.

Comment: The OP is asking to sort by value, not key.

Comment: my bad. I was a bit confused and that is why I mentioned in my first sentence for that.